# How to run the command df and add the space available in perl?

Tags: perl

I have a question on how to make a Perl script where I run the `df` command and add the space available field. Is there something like the Python command in Perl?

```
a = commands.getstatusoutput ( "df /")
```

Comment: Although your question is a bit clear from title still you should try adding the description in English.

Comment: Maybe you should try `qx'df /'`?

Answer (score 3):

See [Filesys::DfPortable](http://search.cpan.org/~iguthrie/Filesys-DfPortable-0.85/DfPortable.pm).

> The module should work with all versions of Windows (95 and up), and
>   with all flavors of Unix that implement the statvfs or the statfs
>   calls. This would include Linux, *BSD, HP-UX, AIX, Solaris, Mac OS X,
>   Irix, Cygwin, etc ...

Synopsis:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Filesys::DfPortable;

my $ref = dfportable("/", 1024); # Display output in 1K blocks
if(defined($ref)) {
 print"Total 1k blocks: $ref->{blocks}\n";
 print"Total 1k blocks free: $ref->{bfree}\n";
 print"Total 1k blocks avail to me: $ref->{bavail}\n";
 print"Total 1k blocks used: $ref->{bused}\n";
 print"Percent full: $ref->{per}\n"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try running `Filesys::Df`.  [perldoc Filesys::Df](http://search.cpan.org/~iguthrie/Filesys-Df-0.92/Df.pm)